# Using Mathematica's Position Function

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language

I have a list `a = {-1, 2/3, -2 - 4 I, -2 + 7 I, 2 I}` and when I use the `Position[a, I]` it returns `{}` which is what one should expect.

However, when I create another list `c = Join[a, {1 + I Sqrt[3], I}]` and then do `Position[c, I]` I get this result `{{6, 2, 1}, {7}}`. Which at first glance can be very strange because what Mathematica does here is to apply the `Position` function on `FullForm[c]`, that is, `Apply[Position[#, I] &, FullForm[c]]`.

Is there a way to make `Position[a, I]` to only return `{{7}}` and not `{{6, 2, 1}, {7}}`? I know one can do `Last[Position[a, I]]` which will give the required answer, however this is does not work in general since `I` can occur anywhere in the list `c`.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
Position[c, I, {1}]
```

or

```
Position[N@c, N@I]
```

Then I'd like to point out that, your explanation *"what* Mathematica *does here is to apply the `Position` function on `FullForm[c]`"* is **incorrect**, because `FullForm` always represents the essence of the code, `Position` is just trying to find the `FullForm` of the pattern in the `FullForm` of the list, it has done nothing strange on `c`:

```
I // FullForm
(* Complex[0, 1] *)
a // FullForm
(* List[-1, Rational[2, 3], Complex[-2, -4], Complex[-2, 7], Complex[0, 2]] *)
{1 + I Sqrt[3], I} // FullForm
(* List[Plus[1, Times[Complex[0, 1], Power[3, Rational[1, 2]]]], Complex[0, 1]] *)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Sorry for the miscommunication. Of course its  because there is no `Complex[0, 1]` in the list `a` that is why `Position[a, I]` returns `{}`.