# Why can't I replace I with HoldPattern@I?

Tags: pattern-matching, complex

Just try this sample:

```
I /. HoldPattern@I -> a
(* I *)
```

Why does it fail to replace `I` with `a`? I've checked `// Hold // FullForm` but found nothing useful.

Comment: Because `I` evaluates internally as `Complex[0,1]`, so `I /. HoldPattern[Complex[0, _]] -> a` would work, or even `I /. HoldPattern[Complex[0, 1]] -> a`

Comment: It's funny that `I /. (Unevaluated@I) -> a` returns `a`. Of course `2 I /. (Unevaluated@I) -> a` already does not do anything.

Comment: I feel obliged to suggest [this interesting read](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XPuK5kX6W8E/discussion[1-25]) as somewhat relevant here.

Comment: @JasonB At the same time both `I` and `Complex[0, 1]` are `Atom`ic: `{AtomQ[I], AtomQ[Complex[0, 1]]}` returns `{True, True}`. But `Complex[0, _]` is not `Atom`ic...

Comment: @RolfMertig, just as `I/.I->a` works fine as well, but I assume OP has a reason for not wanting to do that

Comment: Scratch that, it won't work with  the fancy script `I`.  This is the most general, but it doesn't need `HoldPattern` to work:    `I /. HoldPattern[Complex[r_, i_]] :> r + a i`

Comment: @JasonB Seems that I'm not mature enough…I swear I know about the structure of complex number in _Mathematica_ but simply forgot about it when encountering this! You can consider writing an answer. "I assume OP has a reason for not wanting to do that", yeah, the original problem is something like `… /. HoldPattern@FourierTransform[a, t, I w] :> …`

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov `AtomQ`  doesn't have a `Hold*` attribute so I think one need `AtomQ@Unevaluated@I` to check if `I` is an atom, the result is still `True` anyway.

Comment: These things are confusing.  Sure, after I read the question, I knew the reason for the behaviour.  *But I wouldn't have anticipated the behaviour if you didn't point it out!*

Comment: I'm surprised that this seems to be just now showing up on this site.

Comment: "There is no 'I' in Complex[0,1]", as my coach used to tell us...

Comment: @RolfMertig Somewhat surprisingly, `Trace` shows that `Unevaluated` actually doesn't managed to make `I` unevaluated in `I /. (Unevaluated@I) -> a`. To make the issue more obvious, just check the outputs of `Unevaluated[1 + 1] -> a` and `Unevaluated[1 + 1]~rule~a`. Not sure if it should be taken as a special behavior of `Rule` or there's a more general issue behind. (Maybe I should ask a new question?)

Comment: I am fairly certain that this is a duplicate, either of a Question here or on Stack Overflow.  Can anyone help me find the original?

Comment: Related: [(99336)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99336/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@xzczd has always struck me as a very mature person, and this question hasn't really changed that opinion  :-)

The answer is because `I` evaluates internally as `Complex[0,1]`, so

```
I /. HoldPattern[Complex[0, _]] -> a
```

would work, or even

```
I /. HoldPattern[Complex[0, 1]] -> a
```

and in a more practical example,

```
FourierTransform[f[tt], tt, I ww] /. 
 HoldPattern@FourierTransform[a_, t_, Complex[0, 1] w_] :> 
  myfourier[a, t, J w]
(* myfourier[f[tt], tt, J ww] *)
```